# C#, absolute beginner getting CS1513 C# } expected error

Tags: c#

This is my very first day of programming without having any programming background. I was trying the below code. Please click the below link for the screenshot.

[CS1513  C# } expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmZ6a.png)

HelloWorld.cs:

```cs
namespace HelloWorld {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 -3 and press Enter.");
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if(userValue == "1"); {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats, you have won a cat!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing is here for you!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why did this error occur?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have more { than you do }

Comment: no need for the semicolon on line 15.

Comment: Remove the ; after the if clause

Comment: remove `;` after condition

Comment: Brace (and parenthesis) counting is an excellent day 1 exercise.  Indenting every occurrence of `{` is a great way to determine where you missed one.  Also, it is good form to post _code_ on SO instead of _images_ of code.

Comment: There are zero reasons to post an image of your code. It's much easier to just copy and paste the code itself and format it than it is to capture the screen, save the file, and upload it. Images are also more difficult to read, and you can't copy/paste the code for testing. Code should be included *here*, in your post itself, as text.

Comment: @KenWhite - not to mention, that for some, imgur is blocked!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Yep. There are lots more reasons - see this [Meta answer I wrote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a longer list of the reasons to avoid images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a stray semicolon after your `if` statement. Because of that, the compiler sees your braces as just defining a random block of code (which is valid) but it doesn't understand why you have an `else` after that.

Answer (score 2):

if we use access specifiers inside the static main function for creating the variables like string, it will give this error.

for ex:-

```
namespace ExamplePrgs
{
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            public string check_error;//don't use public here. Delete it, it will not show error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement has a semicolon on the end, if you remove that it will compile just fine!

From

```
(uservalue == 1) ;
{
    //code
}
```

To

```
(uservalue == 1)
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, after investigating my code, I noted at the end of my script, I had a " {} " which had no use (essentially), so after I had removed that, my code passed.